# Modulus and Congruences, odd example.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

Hey guys I am reading a math book and I got a bit confused on the congruence chapter.
I have just seen that $a \pmod n$ = remainder of n|a.
However as an example of " a (mod n) = remainder ", they wrote:

> 1 = 15 (mod 7) 
> The peculiar example was: "The integer 29 is 5 mod 6"

Which I understand it would translate as: $$29 = 5 (mod 6)$$
I do know that 29 is congruent to 5 (mod 6), as
$$6 \mid (29-5) = 4 $$
thus, $29 \equiv 5 (mod 6)$.
However 29 is not at all the remainder of $6\mid 5$ so I am confused as
to me this example does not make sense (being an example or congruence rather than the remainder). It feels like it is badly written. Please help.

Comment: $5$ is the remainder when $29$ is divided by $6$. In general, $a \mod n$ is supposed to be the remainder left when $a$ is divided by $n$.

Comment: It actually means that $6$ divides $29-5=\color{red}24$, or that $29$ and $5$ have the same remainder upon division by $6$, which is true.

Comment: So "29 is 5 mod 6" is logically equivalent to:  29 mod 6 = 5 ? Wouldn't it be 5 is 29 mod 6?

Comment: @RSM: equality is a symmetric relation anyway…

Comment: @Bernard yes, but 5 = 29 mod 6 is not equal to 29 = 5 mod 6 (which is not). Or what are you trying to highlight?

Comment: We write $a\equiv b\pmod n$ to mean that $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$. Note the congruence symbol $\equiv$. This is **not** an equals sign. Many beginners write it as an equals sign and start to believe it means that $a$ equals something called "$b\pmod n$". It doesn't.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I understand that, reason why I did not use the $ \equiv $. I also said that I can see how 29 is congruent 5 mod 6, that is 6 | (29 - 5) or $29 \equiv 5 mod 6$. But that is not what i am asking. It was stated that a mod b = remainder, not congruent ($\equiv$) to the remainder.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: I often write things like  $a=b \mod n$ because I think in terms of congruence classes.

Comment: @RSM: But you may write consistenly $5=29\bmod6$ – which not the same as $5=29\mod 6$ (note the different spacing).

Comment: @Bernard Are you really using lengths of spacing to distinguish semantics? Have you ever programmed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language) ?

Comment: These lengths are obtained with two different commands in LaTeX (which work also in MathJax): `\mod` and `\bmod`. This is quite standard, as far as I know.

Comment: @Bernard What differences are you highlighting between them. I have also not see that notation on my book either. Are you using that instead of parenthesis or the $\equiv$ symbol?

Comment: Actually, the writing with the longer spacing is correct only if you use the congruence symbol, whereas the shorter is correct with the = sign, as it denotes the mod function.

Comment: @Bernard So 5 = 29 mod 6 = remainder, but if we use the congruence notation then  $5 \equiv 29 \mod 6$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In terms of code, you can use `\mod`, or `\\pmod` if you want parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

29 is 5 mod 6 means that 29 mod 6 is same as 5 mod 6. When you divide 29 by 6, you get 5 which is same as 5 mod 6. So it is actually 29 mod 6 =5 mod 6, which is in general stated as 29 is 5 mod 6.

Comment: Thank you, that clears some of the fog for me. I can see how both remainders on $29 mod 6$ and $5 mod 6$ would be the same. But 29 is not equivalent to 29 mod 6 so I am not sure how we can just substitute the 29 entirely. Is there a good place where I can check on this notations, the book doesn't say anything about how to read those kind of sentences.

Comment: Any book on elementary number theory will be of help to you. David Burton is a book I personally like for number theory.

Comment: So the word "is" states a congruence always? or the meaning is given based on context. Which is odd to me as math doesn't tend to be so ambiguous (like 29 is (20+9), I would never understand that as 29 mod n = 20 + 9 ). I will look into the book as it seems mine is not well written. I am not sure I am making sense, but you seem to be the only who meant what i was asking and answered, so thank you!

Comment: See, in the context of congruence, from the statement you gave, it means that with respect to mod 6, 29 mod 6 is equal to 5 mod 6, which in short has been expressed as 29 is 5 mod 6. I hope this is making sense to you. Don't try to confuse yourself with the word "is" here, it's simply with respect to congruence modulo 6 (or n in general). Not to generalise this "is" with other mathematical operations or any relations.

Comment: I see!  do you think It would It be correct for me to write it symbolically as: (29 = 5) mod 6 ? Other than that I think you have answered my question <3.

Comment: Glad that you got your answer. I doubt the validity of the notation you have used. $ 29 \equiv 5 \left(mod 6\right)$ is the most appropriate one. This means that mod 6 is being applied to both the numbers 29 and 5.

Answer (score 2):

The notation is ambiguous.  You are parsing it as

$$29 = (5 \text{ mod } 6)$$

but the correct parsing is

$$29 \equiv 5 ~(\text{mod } 6)$$

which is taken to mean the equation is true modulo 6.

Comment: By congruence definition $$ 29 \equiv 5 (mod 6) $$ is correct, while $$ 29 =  5 (mod 6) $$ is incorrect as 29 should be the remainder of a|n as defined. That is why I do not understand.